# Project in Xcode with unity 5.3.4 and IPAD 2 shows the splash screen then close the app

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, ipad-2

My project in xcode generated from Unity 5.3.4 , shows only the splash screen then close the app, only happens in Ipad2 in my iphone 5 works fine. both have ios 9.2

[Show this message after close the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GK8IT.jpg)

My log:

```
2016-04-25 17:42:56.385 catalogo[1656:63636] -> registered mono modules 0xda0090
-> applicationDidFinishLaunching()
-> applicationDidBecomeActive()
Renderer: PowerVR SGX 543
Vendor:   Imagination Technologies
Version:  OpenGL ES 2.0 IMGSGX543-124.1
GLES:     2
GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap GL_OES_mapbuffer GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_EXT_blend_minmax GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float GL_EXT_debug_label GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer GL_EXT_draw_instanced GL_EXT_instanced_arrays GL_EXT_map_buffer_range GL_EXT_occlusion_query_boolean GL_EXT_pvrtc_sRGB GL_EXT_read_format_bgra GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch GL_EXT_shader_texture_lod GL_EXT_shadow_samplers GL_EXT_sRGB GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_EXT_texture_rg GL_EXT_texture_storage GL_APPLE_clip_distance GL_APPLE_color_buffer_packed_float GL_APPLE_copy_texture_levels GL_APPLE_framebuffer_multisample GL_APPLE_rgb_422 GL_APPLE_sync GL_APPLE_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_APPLE_texture_max_level GL_APPLE_texture_packed_float GL_IMG_read_format GL_IMG_texture_comp
ression_pvrtc 
OPENGL LOG: Creating OpenGL ES 2.0 graphics device
Initialize engine version: 5.3.4f1 (fdbb5133b820)
```

Comment: Does your app implement many shaders? If so, you are probably using Shaders which implement techniques unsupported by OpenGL2.0 where as iPhone 5 is OpenGL3.0. Additionally, iPad 2 has lower memory capacity 1GB compared to 512MB in the iPad2 so it may also be trying to over allocate memory.

Comment: The picture you give tells that your device is disconnected, did you do that afterwards or did it show while processing? It could be your device gets lost either for bad connection (power cord is broken/ faulty) or you may have dust in the connection of your device. This happens when you keep your phone in the pocket and then put it to charge, the dust gets pushed and prevent the cord to fully connect. I had a similar issue.

Comment: @Everts this happens when the application crashes in debug mode.

Comment: When I change the quality to "fasted" (Edit->Project Settings->Quality->Fasted) and exports all project works fine in ipad 2 but the textures is horrible. The attribute is "Texture Quality" I put "Half res" works, but If I put "FULL RES" the app only appear the splash screen then the app close. Sorry by my English. how solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This could be anything causing the problem but the typical way to know if this from Unity or iOS is to first update Unity. Unity 5.4 **fixed** many crashing problems in iOS, according to the release note. I suggest you update to [5.4.0B15](http://unity3d.com/unity/beta).